# Combining time series into single plot with different time instances

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a large dataframe like the one below, from which I want to plot a time series showing a line for the temperature from each sender over time.

```
                utctime      sender  temp_3
500 2014-10-24 11:21:08           e    24.7
501 2014-10-24 11:21:09           d    22.8
502 2014-10-24 11:21:09           a    23.2
503 2014-10-24 11:21:09           c    24.3
504 2014-10-24 11:21:10           b    23.9
505 2014-10-24 11:21:10           e    24.7
506 2014-10-24 11:21:11           d    22.9
507 2014-10-24 11:21:11           a    23.1
508 2014-10-24 11:21:11           c    24.2
509 2014-10-24 11:21:12           b    23.9
510 2014-10-24 11:21:12           e    24.7
511 2014-10-24 11:21:13           d    22.9
512 2014-10-24 11:21:13           a    23.1
513 2014-10-24 11:21:13           c    24.2
514 2014-10-24 11:21:14           b    23.9
```

I tried using filtering to pull out a Series for each sender temps, and then recombining these into a new dataframe, but the times are all different. Is there another way to do this? I'm new to this, so apologise if this is a repeat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby()` method to group by sender, then plot.
As an example:

```
plotaxis = plt.figure().gca()
for key, grp in dataframe.groupby(['sender']):
    my_ts = [ts.to_julian_date() - 1721424.5
             for ts in grp['utctime'].dropna()]
    plt.plot(my_ts,
             grp['temp_3'].dropna(),
             label='%s@%s' % (Temperature, key))
# Style the resulting plot
plotaxis.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y\n%H:%M')
)
```

Comment: Thanks @valtuarte, can you unpack that a little for me? ts.to_julian_date converts the datetimes to strings, but why did you -1721424.5? And is any data lost using the dropna? Finally, is it possible to get the xticks to be the dates (%d%m%y etc)?

Comment: In my case, the column with the timestamps (was actually the index) type was 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex', plotting directly with pyplot didn't show the date (only time) in the x axis, so I converted pandas.DatetimeIndex to Float64Index. The weird calculation there converts julian to "Common Era" dates (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rata_Die). While grouping the index will remain the same and the holes are filled in with NaNs, hereby the dropna(). In your case, if the dtype of 'utctime' is str, try using pd.to_datetime().

Comment: Ok, utctime is a datetime, so I used .set_index, but then the grp['utctime'].dropna() doesn't work?

Comment: try with grp['temp_3'].dropna().index

Comment: My apologies, I forgot the lines where you actually set the x-axis format, fixed now.

Comment: @valtuarter - one more thing, I'm not getting the labels through when I run this script, but I don't know why?

Comment: You mean there is no legend at all?

Comment: Nope, no legend at all

Comment: Add this at the end: plotaxis.legend(loc='best')